# Complex number, logarithm

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Find

i)log(e)

ii)log(i)

I do not know if these issues are of simple fact, that there is something behind. I did

i)Since $log$ and $e$ are inverse functions so$$log(e)=log(e^1)=1$$

Knowing that $z$ is a complex number $\log z=\log(re^{i\theta})=\log r+i\theta$ then

ii)$$log(i)=log(1)+i\theta=i\theta\space \space r>0,\space -\pi<\theta<\pi$$

Comment: A particular solution for Q.(ii) will be $\log(i)=\dfrac{\pi}{2}i$ in the range $[0,\pi]$. There'll be an infinite number of solutions for Q.(ii) actually because of Euler's formula and periodicity of trigonometric functions.

Comment: @PrasunBiswas The way I wrote the solution is wrong?

Comment: I don't understand your problem. Could you rephrase the question in your comment above?

Comment: In your solution, you haven't specified what $\theta$ is. So it's not complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Log on the complex plan is a multivaluated function so you don't get only one answer, by the way you have:

$\ln(1)=2k\pi i$ where $k\in \Bbb Z$

$\ln(i)=\frac {\pi} 2i+2k\pi i$ with again $k\in \Bbb Z$

By setting $k=0$ you get the principal branch.